# The structure includes reference types

Tags: c#, object, struct, reference

Is it the right way for a structure to contain a reference field?

Like the following code:

```
public class ClassA
{
   //...
}

public class ClassB
{
   //...
}

public struct StructAB
{
   public ClassA a;
   public ClassB b;

   public StructAB(ClassA ca,ClassB cb)
   {
      this.a = ca;
      this.b = cb;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that your code might not be "the right way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can and the code will compile. But remember that structs are value types. A *shallow* copy of every member will be created every time the struct is passed as a parameter.
If your struct contains a reference type, then only the reference (i.e. pointer to the member) will be copied.
Therefore, unless there is a good reason for you to use reference types inside a struct, avoid it.

> Typically, you use structure types to design small data-centric types
> that provide little or no behavior. For example, .NET uses structure
> types to represent a number (both integer and real), a Boolean value,
> a Unicode character, a time instance. If you're focused on the
> behavior of a type, consider defining a class. Class types have
> reference semantics. That is, a variable of a class type contains a
> reference to an instance of the type, not the instance itself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#passing-structure-type-variables-by-reference